# How do I restrict a user to visit a particular page only certain no of times?

Tags: 6, nodes

How do I restrict a user (role) to visit a particular page only certain number of of times? I am using Drupal 6. It is for premium content. I just want to give 5 premium content views for free.

Comment: Can you try to use: Rules module and PHP filter. After determine the view count for the node you can redirect or limit user for view that node. That's my idea

Comment: Already answered: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73397/block-node-access-after-a-certain-amount-of-views/73399#73399

Comment: It's actually not a duplicate.  This is about Drupal 6, and the linked question is for Drupal 7.  The answer on the linked question will also only work for Drupal 7, as that hook doesn't exist in Drupal 6.

Comment: @MPD It does exist, it's just named [hook_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!node.php/function/hook_access/6) instead.

Comment: @MPD Same hook, same question, no version tags on neither, just one little rename in API - I don't think it should be 2 questions. I updated my answer there.

Comment: @Mołot No, it's not the same hook. With Drupal 6, only the modules defining a content type can use `hook_access()`. In Drupal jargon, such modules are called _node modules_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - OK, corrected my answer there to use hook_nodeapi(). All in all, it's still the same solution, just different function called.

Comment: @Mołot Uhmmm, no. If you are using a different hook, the solution is not the same, especially if the code used to implement those hooks would be different.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Only differences are in the way current user is inputed and forbidden outputted. all the logic, including switch($op), stays the same. Does `drupal_access_denied()` vs `return false` really makes solution so different it deserves to be a separate question? I don't believe it does. And that's the only significant code change in implementation.

Comment: @Mołot Apart that I doubt `hook_nodepi()` should be calling `drupal_access_denied()` or redirecting the user in anyway, the code used for `hook_nodeapi()` is not the same code used for `hook_node_access()`, and not only for the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict a casual user to only 5 views of ANY premium content, versus restricting his/her looking at the same piece of content 5 times, you might want to consider storing this information in the user's data field.

In broad strokes, you could in a custom module's nodeapi hook, do something like this:

```
if op is view
  if type is premium
    if user doesn't have a premium role assigned
      load the full user object
      if s/he has seen 5 pieces of content
        drupal_goto signup page
      else
        increment count of free page views
        save user
        if this is the 5th view
          tell user this is the last freebie
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi
fi
```

Look into [user_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/6) and [user_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_load/6) for how to save and load serialized information into and from the data field/column of the user.  Also look into [hook_nodeapi()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) for how to intercept these views.

Also caveats you will have to be aware of is cron and search, you probably don't want them to be limited by this, and that drupal_goto in there might/will reek havoc if it isn't trapped for these purposes.